# Transformer object appends namespace automatically to child elements

Tags: java, xml, saxparser, xmlreader, transformer-model

In order to make some changes on XML file, I use the code below:

```
  public boolean run() throws Exception {
    XMLReader xr = new XMLFilterImpl(XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader()) {

     public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
          if(AddRuleReq&& qName.equalsIgnoreCase("cp:ruleset"))
           {
             attributeList.clear();
             attributeList.addAttribute(uri, localName, "id", "int", Integer.toString(getNewRuleId()));
             super.startElement(uri, localName, "cp:rule", attributeList);
             attributeList.clear();
             super.startElement(uri, localName, "cp:conditions", attributeList);
             super.startElement(uri, localName, "SOMECONDITION", attributeList);
             super.endElement(uri, localName, "SOMECONDITION");
             super.endElement(uri, localName, "cp:conditions");
             super.startElement(uri, localName, "cp:actions", attributeList);
             super.startElement(uri, localName, "allow", attributeList);
             super.characters(BooleanVariable.toCharArray(), 0, BooleanVariable.length());
             super.endElement(uri, localName, "allow");
             super.endElement(uri, localName, "cp:actions");
           }
      }
};
  Source source = new SAXSource(xr, new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
  stringWriter = new StringWriter();
  StreamResult result = new StreamResult(stringWriter);
  Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
  transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
  transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
  transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "3");
  transformer.transform(source, result);
  return stringWriter.toString();
}
```

I have pasted a little part of it and it works. But with little differences.

What I expect to see is:

```
<cp:rule id="1">
  <cp:conditions>
    <SOMECONDITION/>
  </cp:conditions>
  <cp:actions>
  <allow>
    true
  </allow>
  </cp:actions>
</cp:rule>
```

What I see is:

```
<cp:rule id="1">
  <cp:conditions>
    <SOMECONDITION xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:common-policy"/>
  </cp:conditions>
  <cp:actions>
  <allow xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:common-policy">
    true
  </allow>
  </cp:actions>
</cp:rule>
```

The processed XML is also invalid according to my schema and unusable for the next time.

My question is that, how can I prevent this namespaces (as in this example, < SOMECONDITION xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:common-policy"/>) being added to child elements?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `startElement` method for the `allow` tag with the wrong parameters, I'm surprised your xml processor is not throwing an error for this:

```
super.startElement(uri, localName, "allow", attributeList);
```

Here `uri` is the namespace uri of the `cp:ruleset` element which you got as a parameter, and `localName` is the name of the `ruleset` element. Correct should be the following, using an empty string as the namespace uri and matching values for qname and local name.

```
super.startElement("", "allow", "allow", attributeList);
```

The same applies to your other `startElement`/`endElement` calls, instead of

```
super.startElement(uri, localName, "cp:rule", attributeList);
```

It should be

```
super.startElement(uri, "rule", "cp:rule", attributeList);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you have corrected a huge misunderstanding.